# Why doesn't Dijkstra's algorithm work as it should for given graph?

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

I have the following code, Dijkstra's algorithm, that I made using [Wikipedia's article on the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm).

For the given graph (see image) and starting node (1), it returns 5 as distance to node (4), which is obviously false. However, when going from node (4), it returns 4 as distance to (1), which is correct. What is wrong in my code?

[image: Graph]

```
//source = starting point, adj[] = adjacency list
private static int dijkstra (int source, ArrayList<Road>[] adj) {
    HashSet<Integer> vertices = new HashSet<>();

    int[] dist = new int[adj.length];
    int[] prev = new int[adj.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < adj.length; i++) {
        dist[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        prev[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        vertices.add(i);
    }

    dist[source] = 0;

    while (!vertices.isEmpty()) {
        int current = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int v: vertices) {
            if (dist[v] < current) {
                current = v;
            }
        }
        vertices.remove(current);

        for (Road v: adj[current]) {
            int alt = dist[current] + v.distance;

            if (alt < dist[v.end]) {
                dist[v.end] = alt;
                prev[v.end] = current;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Road {
    int end;
    int distance;
}

//This loop builds adjacency list from input such as "1 3 2", where 1 represents
// starting node, 3 represents end node and 2 represents weight of that edge.
//start and end values are decremented in order to be 0-indexed

for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    int start = in.nextInt() - 1;
    int end = in.nextInt() - 1 ;
    int dist = in.nextInt();

    adj[start].add(new Road(end, dist));
    adj[end].add(new Road(start, dist));
}
```

Comment: @Mshnik The distance from (1) to (4) is 4. 1->3->2->4

Comment: But (1) -> (3) -> (2) -> (4) = 2 + 1 + 1 = 4. Shouldn't dijkstra work if some path goes backwards as well?

Comment: I guess you built your graph incorrectly. Most likely you just forgot to add the edge `3->2`.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried using a debugger; or using print statements to observe what your code is doing?

Comment: @leonz Depends upon the implementation. In your case the graph is implemented as a directed graph, so the answer is no.

Comment: @Paul I didn't forgot to add that edge, this code gives me correct value when going (4) -> (1), which should be the same as (1) -> (4). And adjacency list, in this case, is representation of an undirected graph. Are you saying this code is for directed graph, because I don't think it should be?

Comment: @leonz the fact that your graph contains the correct path in one direction doesn't imply that it's the case in the opposite direction. You're graph is a **directed graph** per implementation. The adjacency list is built as a map from a vertex to edges that it's part of. This definitely is a directed graph per structural definition. As for the missing (?) edge: hard to tell without seeing the instantiation of the graph, but it's the most likely explanation

Comment: @Paul I added the code that builds the adjacency list from inputs such as "1 3 2", which represents edge (1) -> (3). Is this the way it should be or maybe I made an error here?

Comment: @leonz nope. The graph-building produces a graph that is de facto undirected. I'm going through the code again to find the mistake.

Comment: @Paul using debugger I found out that this is happening due to path of (1) -> (2) not being shortest in the moment that distance to (4) is set. (1) -> (2) is equal to 4 at that moment, so (1) -> (4) is set to 5 and only after that is (1)->(2) set to 3. Maybe this is a hint to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code is causing the error:

```
int current = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int v: vertices) {
    if (dist[v] < current) {
        current = v;
    }
}
```

I assume it's supposed to search the unvisited node that has the shortest path from the start-vertex. But this should look rather like this:

```
int currentPathLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE, current = -1;
for (int v: vertices) {
    if (dist[v] < currentPathLen) {
        current = v;
        currentPathLen = dist[current];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working now. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: @leonz glad to help :)